# Conjecture $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{a_i^{2}}{a_{i+1}^{2}+a_{i}^{2}}}\leq n-1$ for $n\geq 4$ and $a_i>0$ where $a_{n+1}=a_1$

Tags: inequality

Problem/Conjecture :

Let $a_i>0$ and $n\geq 4$ an integer then it seems we have :

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{a_i^{2}}{a_{i+1}^{2}+a_{i}^{2}}}\leq n-1$$

Where : $a_{n+1}=a_1$

I don't use numeric example but there is an argument wich is positive to think the above statement is true :

I check with Desmos and for $x^2+y^2\leq 0.275$ it seems we have :

$$g\left(x,y\right)=\cos\left(\operatorname{arccot}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right)+\left(-\sin^{2}\left(\operatorname{arccot}\left(x\right)+1\right)+\sin^{2}\left(\operatorname{arccot}\left(y\right)+1\right)\right)-\left(1-\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)\right)\leq 0$$

Where :

$$\cos\left(\operatorname{arccot}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right)=\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}}$$

For positive $x,y$ non equal to zero .

Where I'm not sure is as the inequality is homogeneous can we assume :

$$2\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2=1\quad ?$$

If so summing yields the inequality .

Ps : see also [Prove that $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}+\frac{d}{\sqrt{d^2+a^2}}\leq3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4456286/prove-that-fraca-sqrta2b2-fracb-sqrtb2c2-fracc-sqrtc2/4477562#4477562)

Question :

How to (dis)prove it ?

Comment: If the inequality fits in, we can say that:
$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}\Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{a_i} \Bigg) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{\dfrac{a_i^2}{a_{i+1}^2+a_{i}^2}} \leq n-1$

By https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4167145/979028...

Comment: @RDK Thanks for the comment . Do you think that my argument is right ?